# Twitter Bootstrap 3 popover not showing from the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I did find similar questions but it didn't help me in my case.

Basically i show an info popover when i click on an anchor. I realize this with the following js code

```
$("[data-popover]").click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).data('popover');
  var popoverContentId = $(this).data('popover-content');
  var popoverPlacement = $(this).data('placement');
  var popoverWidth = $(this).data('width');
  var htmlContent = $(popoverContentId).html();
  $(selector).popover({placement: popoverPlacement, title: '', width: popoverWidth, content: htmlContent, html: true});
});
```

Now with this code, the first click nothing happens, but afterwards it works just fine with a single click.

How to show the popover from the first click ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(selector).popover` only enables the popover. It doesn't need to be in a click event.
I would change the `.click` to say `.each`

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem !